# Is Content Provider still appropriate way for communication?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I want to know how to open files in the app that are present in other apps.
Like Gmail, What's app use file sharing(Attach file) from Gallery and File Manager.
(Could you Suggest a elegant way to do this)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question and explain, in detail, what "open files in the app that are present in other apps" means?

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what "use file sharing from Gallery and File Manager" means.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In Gmail, When click on Attach file option-> it shows files present in the file system to select and selected file gets loaded . I want to know how this scenario implemented.